# Android application signing: Proguard returned with error code 1. see console

Tags: android, proguard, android-build

I have built an application that uses JacksonJson as a library. I am trying to export it as a signed application and getting the proguard error. I have tried various solutions posted on the internet, but none seems to work. Any help will be appreciated.

**Console**:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonMappingExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.JsonParseExceptionMapper: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase: can't find referenced class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 67 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Here is my **project.properties** file:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-18
android.library.reference.3=../ABCSourceCode/Libraries/ABCLibrary
android.library.reference.4=../ABCSourceCode/Libraries/AndroidHorizontalListView
android.library.reference.1=../ABCSourceCode/Libraries/ABS_Library
android.library.reference.2=../ABCSourceCode/Libraries/google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.6=../ABCSourceCode/Libraries/volleyLibrary
android.library.reference.5=../ABCSourceCode/Libraries/SlidingMenuForklibrary
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IN proguard config file, just skip all the above libs which are thrown in error by below mentioned way..

```
 -keep class yourclassname.** { *; }
```

In your case it would be

```
 -keep class javax.ws.rs.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
```

Try doing this and run build again.

Comment: Tried adding it to my proguard-project.txt, but nothing happened. Any other alternatives?

Comment: It worked. I was making the changes in my local .txt file, instead of the one present in the sdk tools. Also, I had to add the following line: `-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**`. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: `-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.**{*;}` did not work. Instead `-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**` did. Kindly edit your answer so that it does not create confusion to viewers later on.